# How to All A WebView Inside a BottomNavigationView Fragment?

Tags: java, android

**Android Studio - Java**

In my new app, I am trying to make a WebView to embed my [Website](https://rajscape.com) into a app. I want a different `WebView` on each tab in my `BottomNavigationView` Widget. 
 **I have 3 tabs.**

1. Home
2. COVID-19 Tracker
3. Dashboard

- Home will have my home page website
- COVID-19 Tracker will have my coronavirus tracker website
- Dashboard will not have any `WebViews`

**What I Have Tried**

- I have used a `RelativeLayout` instead of a `ConstraintLayout`
- I have tried removing the fragment but that just removed the `BottomNavigationView`
- I have tried adding a `LinearLayout`


  **Here is my Code**

*****MainActivity.java*****

```java
package com.example.user.test;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.widget.TextView;
/ * test * /
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView myWebView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById (R.id.webview1);
        // Cancel standard browser
        myWebView.setWebViewClient (new WebViewClient ());
        // JS
        myWebView.getSettings (). setJavaScriptEnabled (true);
        // USERAGENT
        String userAgent = myWebView.getSettings (). GetUserAgentString ();
        myWebView.getSettings (). setUserAgentString (userAgent + "appwebview");
        // URL read when the app starts
        myWebView.loadUrl ("http://test.net");
    }
    public BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener () {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected (@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId ()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    myWebView.loadUrl ("http://test.net/photo");
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                    myWebView.loadUrl ("http://test.net/kiji");
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                    myWebView.loadUrl ("http://test.net/");
                    return true;
            }
             return false;
        }
    };
}
```

***Main_Activity.xml***

```xml
<? xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns: android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns: app = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns: tools = "http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android: id = "@ + id/container"
    android: layout_width = "match_parent"
    android: layout_height = "match_parent"
    android: orientation = "vertical"
    tools: context = "com.example.user.test.MainActivity">
    <WebView
        android: id = "@ + id/webview1"
        android: layout_width = "match_parent"
        android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android: layout_weight = "4.29">
   </WebView>
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android: id = "@ + id/navigation"
        android: layout_width = "match_parent"
        android: layout_height = "77dp"
        android: layout_gravity = "bottom"
        android: background = "? android: attr/windowBackground"
        app: menu = "@ menu/navigation" />
<LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why did you all dislike?

Comment: Hello Raj, welcome to StackOverflow! Probably people disliked because you should tell what you have tried, and more exactly where you are having problems. This question needs to be more specific at what are you stuck. I highly recommend [checking the guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to take a look on how you can improve your question.

Comment: see [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an "actual" question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/839601)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OK, Lets Start From The Dashboard (Does not have any WebViews)**

It does not have any WebViews so lets skip this Fragment.

---

**Next, Lets go to Home**

Go to `MainActivity.java` and put in the WebView Code in there (You put yours in the UI Java Files)

---

**Do The Same To Covid Tracker**